# Text classification - how to approach

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I'll try do describe what I have in mind.

There is a text content stored in MS SQL database. Content comes daily as a stream. Some people go through the content every day and, if the content fits certain criteria, mark it as validated. There is only one category. It's either "valid" or not.

What I want is to create a model based on already validated content, save it and using this model to "pre-validate" or mark new incoming content. Also once in a while to update the model based on a newly validated content.  Hopefully I explained myself clearly.

I am thinking to use Spark streaming for data classification based on model created. And Naive Bayes algorithm. But how would you approach creating, updating and storing the model? There is ~200K+ validated resultants (texts) of various length. Do I need so many for the model?
And how to use this model in Spark Streaming.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow this question is very broad, and more related to `Machine Learning` than to `Apache Spark`, however I will try to give you some hints or steps to follow (I won't do the work for you).

1. Import all the libraries you need

   ```py
   from pyspark.mllib.classification import LogisticRegressionWithSGD, LogisticRegressionModel
   from pyspark.mllib.linalg import SparseVector
   from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint
   import re
   ```
2. Load your data into an [RDD](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=rdd#pyspark.RDD)

   ```py
   msgs = [("I love Star Wars but I can't watch it today", 1.0),
           ("I don't love Star Wars and people want to watch it today", 0.0),
           ("I dislike not being able to watch Star Wars", 1.0),
           ("People who love Star Wars are my friends", 1.0),
           ("I preffer to watch Star Wars on Netflix", 0.0),
           ("George Lucas shouldn't have sold the franchise", 1.0),
           ("Disney makes better movies than everyone else", 0.0)]

   rdd = sc.parallelize(msgs)
   ```
3. **Tokenize** your data (if you use [ML](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html?highlight=ml#module-pyspark.ml) it might be easier) and

   ```py
   rdd = rdd.map(lambda (text, label): ([w.lower() for w in re.split(" +", text)], label))
   ```
4. Remove all unnecessary words (widely known as *stop-words*), and symbols e.g. `,.&`

   ```py
   commons = ["and", "but", "to"]
   rdd = rdd.map(lambda (tokens, label): (filter(lambda token: token not in commons, tokens), label))
   ```
5. Create a dictionary with all `distinct` words in **all your dataset**, it sounds huge but they are not so many as you would expect, and I bet they will fit in your master node (however there are other ways to approach this, but for simplicity I will keep this way).

   ```py
   # finds different words
   words = rdd.flatMap(lambda (tokens, label): tokens).distinct().collect()
   diffwords = len(words)
   ```
6. Convert your `features` into a [DenseVector](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html?highlight=densevector#pyspark.mllib.linalg.DenseVector) or [SparseVector](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html?highlight=densevector#pyspark.mllib.linalg.SparseVector), I would obviously recommend the second way because normally a `SparseVector` requires less space to be represented, however it depends on the data. Note, there are better alternatives like `hashing`, but I am trying to keep loyal to my verbose approach. After that transform the `tuple` into a [LabeledPoint](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html?highlight=labeledpoint#pyspark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint)

   ```py
   def sparsify(length, tokens):
       indices = [words.index(t) for t in set(tokens)]
       quantities = [tokens.count(words[i]) for i in indices]

       return SparseVector(length, [(indices[i], quantities[i]) for i in xrange(len(indices))])

   rdd = rdd.map(lambda (tokens, label): LabeledPoint(label, sparsify(diffwords, tokens)))
   ```
7. Fit your favorite model, in this case I used [LogisticRegressionWithSGD](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html?highlight=logisticregression#pyspark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionWithSGD) due ulterior motives.

   ```py
   lrm = LogisticRegressionWithSGD.train(rdd)
   ```
8. [Save](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html?highlight=logisticregression#pyspark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionModel.save) your model.

   ```py
   lrm.save(sc, "mylovelymodel.model")
   ```
9. [Load](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html?highlight=logisticregression#pyspark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionModel.load) your [LogisticRegressionModel](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html?highlight=logisticregression#pyspark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionModel) in another application.

   ```py
   lrm = LogisticRegressionModel.load(sc, "mylovelymodel.model")
   ```
10. [Predict](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html?highlight=logisticregression#pyspark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionModel.predict) the categories.

    ```py
    lrm.predict(SparseVector(37,[2,4,5,13,15,19,23,26,27,29],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]))
    # outputs 0
    ```

Note that I didn't evaluate the `accuracy` of the model, however it looks very doesn't it?

Comment: Thanks you Alberto for so detailed answer.  And just in time for Star Wars release :).
One question.
Do I always need 2 data sets? In my case one validated by data validators and one omitted?
Can't I just use one data set? Like i just sentences with Star Wars.

Comment: You just need a `training` dataset to train the model, but if you want to evaluate the model (accuracy and overfitting) you would need 2 datasets (both labeled) one to train your model and the other to evaluate it, the second one is called `validation` data. After fitting the model you can predict the `label` for any other text after `sparsify` it, nonetheless I recommend you the course of [Machine Learning by Stanford](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/) don't worry if you can't afford the certificate as me, you can audit it and learn because it's open to everyone.

Comment: Hi Alberto. I built the model and now I have another question. How do I apply the model on incoming data once I load model in another program?

Let's say a text came in "I watched Star Wars today and it was great". How do I apply the model? I think I need tokenize it and create vectors. But how do I label it? All examples I can find do test on labeled sets.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't forget that you are trying to `classify` new data based on old `labeled` data, therefore you are trying to `predict` based on several `features`, in text classification the features can be the words used in the text. Hence, if you are trying to classify data, it's obvious that they won't come labeled, the model will predict the label, that's how [supervised learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supervised_learning) works.
I recommend you to audit this course [Scalable Machine Learning](https://www.edx.org/course/scalable-machine-learning-uc-berkeleyx-cs190-1x)

Comment: I think I need to transform incoming data into vector and pass it to predict method of the model. If I used TF-IDF method to prepare model, I need to prepare vector the same way. Correct?

Comment: Yes, both datasets (training and validation) must have the same structure, otherwise the model will be useless